# deserialize xml into an array of objects, where each object contains nested classes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

So I am having trouble figuring out how to do this, I'll start with the format of my xml which I get from a rest API (simplified)

```
<exportData encryptedPhrase="stuff" version="1" stVersion="1">
<completeAdministrator>
    <administratorData id="1">
        <name>stuff</name>
        <operations>0</operations>
        <administrativeRole>Some role</administrativeRole>
        <encryptedPassphrase>pass</encryptedPassphrase>
        <isChangePassword>false</isChangePassword>
        <isDualAuthRequired>false</isDualAuthRequired>
        <lastLoginTime>2014-12-23T15:00:27-08:00</lastLoginTime>
        <loginFailureCount>0</loginFailureCount>
        <lastFailureLoginTime>2014-12-23T14:54:42-08:00</lastFailureLoginTime>
        <isLockedOut>false</isLockedOut>
        <lastPasswordChangeTime>2014-12-23T15:04:38-08:00</lastPasswordChangeTime>
        <customAttributes>
            <customProperties>
            </customProperties>
            <localCertificates>
            </localCertificates>
            <partnerCertificates>
            </partnerCertificates>
            <userCertificates>
            </userCertificates>
        </customAttributes>
    </administratorData>
    <businessUnit>bu</businessUnit>
    <parentAdministratorName>admin</parentAdministratorName>
</completeAdministrator>
</exportData>
```

So basically I want a main class (exportData) that contains a list of admin objects (completeAdministrator), and each admin object has an adminstratordata object, and a custom attributes object.

I used the Paste Special feature to have .Net create a class for me which seems to work but when I use this code, only the first item is read in. How do I make this work?

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AdminData));
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Projects\SafeXMLImport\ST 5.2.1 export Data & document\adm.xml", FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
AdminData adminXml = (AdminData)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) to create classes, sometimes VisualStudio dont know to create properly classes. I think your xml should have at end the same tag as at begin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. I had to make an array of businessUnits because I found out there can be multiple tags for it in one entry.

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Projects\SafeXMLImport\ST 5.2.1 export Data & document\adm.xml");

        List < CompleteAdministrator > adminList =
            (
                from c in doc.Root.Elements("completeAdministrator")
                select new CompleteAdministrator
                {
                    businessUnits = (from d in c.Elements("businessUnit")
                                     select d.Value).ToArray(), 
                    parentAdministratorName = (string)c.Element("parentAdministratorName"),
                    administratorData =
                    (
                        new AdministratorData
                        {
                            id = (string)c.Element("administratorData").Attribute("id"),
                            name = (string)c.Element("administratorData").Element("name"),
                            operations = (string)c.Element("administratorData").Element("operations"),
                            administrativeRole = (string)c.Element("administratorData").Element("administrativeRole"),
                            encryptedPassphrase = (string)c.Element("administratorData").Element("encryptedPassphrase"),
                            isChangePassword = (string)c.Element("administratorData").Element("isChangePassword"),
                            isDualAuthRequired = (string)c.Element("administratorData").Element("isDualAuthRequired"),
                            lastLoginTime = (string)c.Element("administratorData").Element("lastLoginTime"),
                            loginFailureCount = (string)c.Element("administratorData").Element("loginFailureCount"),
                            lastFailureLoginTime = (string)c.Element("administratorData").Element("lastFailureLoginTime"),
                            isLockedOut = (string)c.Element("administratorData").Element("isLockedOut"),
                            lastPasswordChangeTime = (string)c.Element("administratorData").Element("lastPasswordChangeTime")
                        }
                    )
                }
            ).ToList();
```